# How to add database to setup in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have made a setup for my C# application but when i installed it on another computer, it showed me an error that Path is invalid. I used the following code.

```
        public string Path1 = (@"|DataDirectory|\MakeMyBill.sdf");
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(Path3);
        conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your application is running fine before creating setup and you are just asking the way to include database in setup then-

```
- I put the database with exe [in bin->debug folder]
- and while creating setup i put the database in Application folder with .exe.
  [as you know there are 3 parts in file system -Application folder , user's desktop and user's program menu]
```